# UNION several WITH results

Tags: sql, union, sql-server-2014, unpivot, with-statement

I have two similar queryes.

Like folowing:

```
    with CategoryHistory AS (
    SELECT
    category.GUID as id,
    ----HERE MANY FIELDS----
    category.__$operation AS operation,
    map.tran_begin_time as beginT, 
    map.tran_end_time as endT
    FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_BalanceHC_ZapasCategory(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_BalanceHC_ZapasCategory'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS category
    INNER JOIN  [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] map
        ON category.[__$start_lsn] = map.start_lsn
    )
    SELECT  operation, fields, valueses, beginT, endT FROM CategoryHistory
    unpivot ( [valueses] for fields in
    (

    ----HERE MANY FIELDS----
))p
```

Can i `UNION` of `WITH` results? Problem that i want `UNPIVOT` some fields from result of query.

Comment: Yes, but there might be simpler methods.  I would suggest that you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm using the CDC for grabbing statistic for some tables. Tables can be related but it is don't matter. I  want create view where unpivot some tables and union them in one table.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you simply want something like this:

```
SELECT ch.operation, ch.beginT, ch.endT, v.field, v.val
FROM CategoryHistory ch cross apply
     (values ('field1', field1), ('field2', field2), . . .
     ) f(field, val);
```

I find this easier than using `unpivot`.

Comment: Where in this example join with another table? In my case `CategoryHistory` is an alias...

Comment: @Seva . . . before the `cross apply`.